# file_get_content is not working for a specific link

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am facing a really wired situation, i have two URLs from where i am reading XML content. below is my simple script.

```
$a1 = file_get_contents('http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1678&pid=2323&acc=2323');

var_dump($a1);

echo '<hr>';

$a2 = file_get_contents('http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1066&pid=9922&acc=1154');

var_dump($a2);
```

The first link "a1" exists but when i try to read the URL through **file_get_content** it gives me warning.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1678&pid=2323&acc=2323): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND in serverFilePath/yooy.php on line 2

with return **bool(false)**

and the other link "a2" is working fine and returning the XML Feed.

Any advice.?

Here is a screenshot of the code output run on a single page.
[image]

Comment: That link is not showing any result that's why you got en error.

Comment: `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND` is pretty self explaining.

Comment: use `if( get_headers($url)[0] != "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found" ){}` to check if the url is not 404 then use `file_get_contents` so that you will not get this type of error, but if you will use it in a loop , it will make your application slow .

Comment: @ajay the url exists if you access it. "[link](http://xml.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1678&pid=2323&acc=2323), plus it is working on my localhost

Comment: thank you, it was an security issue, listing `$a1` was allowed only for specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, the links that you posted(`$a1`, `$a2`), well one of them isn't working, guess which one.

Following is the error that is being returned while accessing `$a1`.

```
Error code: 1001 happened, please check with customer support immediately. 

For assistance, please contact support@propspace.com.
```

While working on an external link/API, Always make it a habit to first make a request to it from outside of PHP, doing so shall rule out any possibilities of errors on the other end, and shall save a lot of valuable debugging time.

If its a simple GET request then simply navigating to it in a browser will do, but if its POST then you can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) extension for chrome it works flawless for me.